# Searching is not working in django rest_framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

Searching is not working in the django rest framework. searching for the approved status of leave applied by a particular employee. But the filtering/ searching/ sorting is properly working in the admin user. but not in the employee side.

## Views.py

```
class LeaveList(APIView):

    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication, TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]  

    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend,SearchFilter,OrderingFilter]
    ordering_fields = ['apply_date','number_of_days','status']
    search_fields = ['status']
    filter_fields = ['status']

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        employee = request.user

        filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend,SearchFilter,OrderingFilter]
        search_fields = ['status']

        queryset = LeaveApplicationModel.objects.filter(employee_id=employee.id)
        serializer_class = LeaveApplicationsListSerializer(queryset, many=True)

        return Response(data=serializer_class.data)
```

## Serializers.py

```
class LeaveApplicationsListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  
    class Meta:
        model = LeaveApplicationModel
        exclude = ['id', 'employee']
```

[postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRKKV.png)
[postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0z4Kr.png)

[expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8j5L2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the `search_filters` anywhere. `GenericAPIView` or any class that subclasses it, e.g. [`ListAPIView`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview), will use it automatically. It's in the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering).

If I were you, I'd rather subclass [`ListAPIView`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview) and set the relevant [available attributes](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview) correctly. You can overwrite `get_queryset` to filter for the employee:

```py
class LeaveList(ListAPIView):
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication, TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]  
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend,SearchFilter,OrderingFilter]
    ordering_fields = ['apply_date','number_of_days','status']
    search_fields = ['status']
    filter_fields = ['status']
    serializer_class = LeaveApplicationsListSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        employee = self.request.user

        return LeaveApplicationModel.objects.filter(employee_id=employee.id)
```

Comment: [D Malan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3486675/d-malan)
Thank you so much..it worked perfectly

Comment: No problem! You can mark an answer as correct if it answered you question.

Comment: @JerinRaju there's a green arrow to the left of the answer that you need to click on. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-can-i-accept-an-answer-and-which-one-should-i-choose).

Comment: [D Malan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3486675/d-malan) ok